# Splitting Vim window into three panels

Tags: vim, window-resize, popupmenu, omnicomplete, jedi-vim

I am new to Vim and I want to consider Vim as a potential code IDE for developing Python and C/C++ codes.

After struggling a lot I finally managed to install enough Plugins such as YCM,color-schemes,... to get a minimum development environment.
What I am struggling to fix are as follows:

1-Vim must automatically split a window into three panels for a python or C/C++ file to edit like the attached image.
Note: The vim or .vimrc setting must be set to be plain for other file types.

2-YouCompleteMe popup menu must be limited in size and get specific background(bg) and font color.

3-The 2 extra panels YCM popup doc and GDB/Compiler output should not write to file and the user should insert only once :q! or :wq to quit from the main file window (user should not close all the panels separately).

4-The compiler/gdb output must be shown in its dedicated window with scroll capability.

Thanks[image: Desired vim IDE with YCM code completion]

Comment: I haven't tried but I feel getting GDB to output continuously in a split will be hard. Vim isn't meant to be an IDE so doesn't allow a shell to run in one of the splits (Plugins might try to emulate this). If you really want a terminal in one of your splits neovim just recently added this. However neovim is in alpha and isn't really stable.

Comment: As for the closing all at once use `:qa` or `:wqa` which quit all

Comment: Vim has never been, is not, will never and can't be an IDE. You are wasting your time.

Comment: While it's true that vim is _not_ an IDE and what you asked for cannot be acheived _through_ vim (unless you use neovim, a fork still in the alpha phase), if you research terminal multiplexers (e.g. [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)) or tiling window managers (e.g. [i3wm](http://i3wm.org/)) I think you can come up with something close to what you asked for.

Comment: Look into vim sessions to set things up the way you want. What you've got is a series of splits, settings, loads, and syntax commands; once you've got things set up the way you want, use :mksession and save it. You'll have to load the file to edit after the session starts, but that's not awful.